# What is the difference between Postman, cURL

Tags: curl, postman

Is Postman just a reformatter for HTTP requests? I also see people using visual studio code to send http requests. Most documentation for APIs show code in cURL but how would I reformat that to be used in Postman, and how would I reformat what is used in Postman to be used in real JS or Python code?

Comment: "how would I reformat what is used in Postman to be used in real JS or Python code" Postman writes that code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to reformat curl for Postman because you can import it via the import raw text option.

[image]

And you can use the code snippet option (on the right side of the client window, usually minimised with the characters `</>` )  to convert to other languages etc. (Select from the drop-down menu.

[image]